# How to avoid duplicate tags (id) being generated when new rows are added to HTML table using jQuery at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

At the outset I wish to put on record that I am not sure as to *what I am going to ask* makes for a proper question as per SO standards. However, here it goes:

I have an HTML table where rows can be added using jQuery during runtime. The number of columns are a reflection of the underlying table fields. In addition to the table fields, I have two extra cells (`td`s) which are being used for:

- Displaying the row number
- A **Delete** link to remove the (respective) row

I am generating `id`s as each new row is being added dynamically. Also, as the new rows are being added, the row number (in the very first cell of the row) is being updated to the next higher number.

All was going as required only then I realized that if the number of additional **rows** goes beyond a certain value, the **row number** input box in a particular row is **blank** and the next row onwards, the numbering continues until a particular row in the next cycles is reached.

As an example, the row numbering continues from 1 till 10, then in the next row misses 11 (as it should have been). If I continue adding more rows, row numbers continue from 12 until 21 (21 goes missing again) and so on. On studying the `id`s, I realized that the **last cell** of the first row incidentally has exact the same `id` as the **first cell** of the 11th row. So, if my generated `id` for the first cell of the 11th row is `id_tIndx111`, the last cell of the first row also has the same id i.e. `id_tIndx111`. (*My head is spinning by now!!*)

**An illustration of the IDs being generated:**

**11th row**, first cell:   `id_tIndx111`       **1st row**, last cell: `id_tIndx111`

**21st row**, first cell:   `id_tIndx211`       **2nd row**, last cell: `id_tIndx211`

The reason for the missing row number is of course due to *duplicate* `id`s being encountered by the browser.

So, what I tried to overcome this malady, is to reduce the number of fields in the underlying table by 1. **And the problem of missing row number seems to have been taken care of!(?)**

**My question is :** What should be the approach under such situations? Because I will not be always at liberty to keep the number of fields in tables to a certain number. And using a table with more than 10 fields will have the issue I have just **described**.

Thanks for going through the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beileve you are generating the id yourself. You can restructure your id. Something like this,

```
id_tIndx1_11
```

In that case  `id_tIndx1_11` and  `id_tIndx11_1` will not be identical. That would solve your problem. If you could add the code for id generation we could help you more preciesly.

Comment: Not to take away anything from your answer, but **I had solved it before your reply** (_marking your reply though_, as it is close to what I did). What I have done is to target the last cell (where I have the link) in the **loop** generating the attributes of table **elements**.  And it is working. (_As they say, sleep over a problem to solve it, I didn't._)